# How do i split a variable in R?

Tags: r, split, stringr

I have the [following dataframe](https://C:%5CUsers%5CGiuli%5COneDrive%5CDocumenti%5Cfin_account) which contains several values for a single row

A tibble: 1,751 x 1
value

1 2 3 5
2 2 4
3 2
4 1 2 3 4

... with 1,741 more rows

The reason for this structure is that I have an online questionnaire which accepts multiple answers to the same question (1,2,3,4,5,6 correspod to answers, each row is a respondant), but the way data is stored is a problem because there's no way to display all the answers stacked without previously manipulating the dataframe.

Unfortunately I do not know how to manipulate the dataframe in a way that every row contains a single value. Alternatively, it could also be useful to have the answers separed into different columns. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share part of your data in a copy-pasteable way with `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))`?

Comment: i am new to stack overflow, let me know if this is what you mean? > dput(head(x))
c("2 3 5", "2 4", "2", "1 2 3 4 5", "2 3 5", "1 2 3 4 5")

Answer (score 0):

Considering your tibble object as df,

Creating a vector of elements in each row:

```
newdf <- strsplit(df$x, " ")
```

Converting the vectors in the list into numeric:

```
newdf <- lapply(newdf, as.numeric)
```

Finding the maximum value in the list:

```
cl <- max(unlist(lapply(newdf, max)))
```

Creating an null matrix with columns for each response:

```
out <- matrix(nrow = nrow(df), ncol = cl)
```

Filling the response columns based on the appearance of the corresponding numbers in the response:

```
for (i in 1:length(newdf)) {
  out[i,] <- 1:cl %in% newdf[[i]]
}
```

Renaming the columns with the option numbers:

```
colnames(out) <- paste("Opt", 1:cl, sep = "_")
```

converting the matrix into a tibble:

```
out <- tibble::as.tibble(out)
```

Final tibble:

```
out
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Opt_1 Opt_2 Opt_3 Opt_4 Opt_5
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
2 FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE
3 FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
4 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
```

**Edit:**

If you are sure about the number of options (here it is 6), you can have

```
cl <- 6
```

If you prefer not to have true or false, you can run this. The values 1 represent that the corresponding option is selected.

```
out <- as.data.frame(out)
for (i in colnames(out)) {
  out[,i] <- as.integer(out[,i])
  }

  Opt_1 Opt_2 Opt_3 Opt_4 Opt_5
1     0     1     1     0     1
2     0     1     0     1     0
3     0     1     0     0     0
4     1     1     1     1     0
```

If you want to have option numbers instead of 0 and 1:

```
out <- as.data.frame(out)
for (i in 1:ncol(out)) {
  out[,i] <- as.integer(out[,i])*i
}



  Opt_1 Opt_2 Opt_3 Opt_4 Opt_5
1     0     2     3     0     5
2     0     2     0     4     0
3     0     2     0     0     0
4     1     2     3     4     0
```

Comment: thanks you! do you also know how to substitute FALSE and TRUE with my values? (1:6)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one-line `tidyr`solution:

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% separate(Var, into = paste0("v", 1:max(str_count(df$Var, "\\d+"))), sep = " ")
  v1   v2   v3   v4   v5
1  2    3    5 <NA> <NA>
2  2    4 <NA> <NA> <NA>
3  2 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4  1    2    3    4    5
5  2    3    5 <NA> <NA>
6  1    2    3    4    5
```

Here, we use `str_count` to count the number of digits per string/row and `max` to determine the maximum number of digits so we have a handle as to how many new columns we need; then we split the strings on whitespace and `separate` the splitted substrings into the newly created columns.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Var = c("2 3 5", "2 4", "2", "1 2 3 4 5", "2 3 5", "1 2 3 4 5"))
```